# function to check if string exists in C linked list

Tags: c, function, linked-list, strcmp

I am writing a program for class and my instructor asked us to check if a name already exists in our list before we add it. The code that I have written to do this does not seem to be working properly.

```
    void doAdd (waitListPtr hd)
{
 /* get group size from input */
int size = getPosInt();
if (size < 1)
{
printf ("Error: Add command requires an integer value of at least 1\n");
printf ("Add command is of form: a <size> <name>\n");
printf ("  where: <size> is the size of the group making the reservation\n");
printf ("         <name> is the name of the group making the reservation\n");
return;
}

/* get group name from input */
char *name = getName();
 if (NULL == name)
{
printf ("Error: Add command requires a name to be given\n");
printf ("Add command is of form: a <size> <name>\n");
printf ("  where: <size> is the size of the group making the reservation\n");
printf ("         <name> is the name of the group making the reservation\n");
return;
}
    if(doesNameExist(hd, name) == TRUE){
        printf("\nERROR: Name already on list");
    }else{
    printf ("Adding group \"%s\" of size %d\n", name, size);
    addToList(&hd, size, name);
    hd->groupStatus = PRESENT;
    }
}
```

It never gives an error and always just adds the name to the list.

Here is the doesNameExist function:

```
int doesNameExist(waitListPtr hd, char* name){

waitListPtr ptr = hd;

while(ptr != NULL){
    if(strcmp(ptr->groupName, name)== 0){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
return FALSE;
```

}

here is the declaration of my linked list structure

```
typedef struct waitListStruct
{
char      groupName[30];
int       groupSize;
int       groupStatus;
struct    waitListStruct*  next;
} waitList;

typedef waitList* waitListPtr;
```

here is the function to add a new node to the list

```
void addToList(waitListPtr* hd, int size, char* name){

waitListPtr ptr = (waitListPtr) malloc (sizeof(waitList));

strcpy(ptr->groupName, name);

ptr->groupSize = size;

ptr->next = *hd;

*hd = ptr;

}
```

this is the part in main where the function is called

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

 waitListPtr head = NULL;


 while ((ch = getNextNWSChar ()) != EOF)
 {
if('a' == ch)
  {
   doAdd(head);
 }
 }
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strcmp(ptr->groupName, &name)== 0){
```

is not right. I am surprised your compiler didn't flag that as an error.

It needs to be:

```
if(strcmp(ptr->groupName, name)== 0){
                    //   ^^ Drop the &
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

The `while` loop in that function can be simplified to:

```
while(ptr != NULL)
{
   if (strcmp(ptr->groupName, name) == 0)
      return TRUE;

   ptr=ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried dropping the &, but I'm getting the same result.
Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: @wuddupjoe, that indicates a problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @wuddupjoe Maybe it has something to do with your `addToList` function.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is occurring because of how I'm storing the name into the linked list?
This is my code for adding a new node.
         void addToList(waitListPtr* hd, int size, char* name){

        waitListPtr ptr = (waitListPtr) malloc (sizeof(waitList));

        strcpy(ptr->groupName, name);

        ptr->groupSize = size;

        ptr->next = *hd;

        *hd = ptr;

        }

Comment: @wuddupjoe, it will be better to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Comments are not the right place to post blocks of code.

Comment: @R.Sahu Sorry about that. Should I edit my main post with the code?

Comment: @wuddupjoe, my recommendation would be to start a new post with my suggested fix applied in the call to `strcmp`

Comment: @R.Sahu Ok. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(ptr != NULL){
    // Remove & from the name , Check man page of strcmp 

    if(strcmp(ptr->groupName, name)== 0){
        return TRUE;
        // Remove this line as it is unreachable as you are returning
        break;
    }
```

Change the logic of addition

```
void addToList(waitListPtr* hd, int size, char* name){

waitListPtr ptr = (waitListPtr) malloc (sizeof(waitList));

strcpy(ptr->groupName, name);

ptr->groupSize = size;

if (*hd == NULL)
{
   ptr->next = NULL;
} else {
    ptr->next = *hd;
}
    *hd = ptr;
}
```

Hope that solve the problem #peace

Comment: If I try replacing ptr->groupName with ptr.groupName, I get an error stating "request for member 'groupName' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: I recommend post the full source code here ,i can help you out . its strange that hd is not ptr and you are not getting error

Comment: I am currently unable to make a new post as it says I can only post a question once every 90 minutes. Is there any way for me to message the code to you?

Comment: @ Sohil Omer typedef waitList* waitListPtr;

Comment: now the problem is adding of name into your link list

Comment: I have added in the relevant code that I used to add a new node to the linked list. I believe the full source code is to long to post and includes a lot of functions that I have not even used yet, since I have been stuck on this part. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I have also just added the part in main where the function in question is called. I have removed the unused functions to make it easier to read,

Comment: Sorry, just realised that I didn't have the entire doAdd function in there before, so I've edited again to include that as well.

Comment: i have changed the logic of add to list function

Comment: I just tried your change and still not getting an error when I try to add the same name twice. :/